# Nested recyclerview Scrollbar height varies during scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I'm Using recyclerview In which its some items(child) are horizontal recyclerview others are layouts.
I've enabled Scrollbar for the root recyclerview.
The Problem i'm facing is whenever i'm scrolling the height of the scrollbar changing according to the itemview.

I want to maintain Fixed scrollbar height.

P.S: Recyclerview inside Nestedscrollview gives fixed height for scrollbar but i want to know solution based on recyclerview only.